# Excel counting with multiple criteria and multiple instances in a single cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula, count, cell, multiple-instances

[image]

I need help with a function which will find all values of 1 in column A (e.g. A1).  For each value of 1, I need the function to count the number of IP addresses beginning with either 178. or 14. in the corresponding column B (e.g. B1).  The IP addresses are separated by a comma & space, e.g. 178.5.4.3, 178.5.4.4

I was able to count the total instances of 178. in column B using this formula:

`=SUM(LEN(A2:A11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A11,"178.",""))/LEN("178."))`

Or this one by adding four spaces in the substitute function:

`=SUM(LEN(A2:A11)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A11,"178.","    ")))`

But, I cannot seem to find a way to search for a 1 in column A (without counting it) and then count the number of 178. and 14. in the corresponding B column.

The purpose is to find out how many IP addresses are in use in zone 1, 2, 3, etc.

```
1   14.38.227.88
1   14.38.227.103
1   14.38.227.104
2   178.32.38.106, 178.32.34.241, 178.32.33.65, 178.32.32.20, 178.32.34.135
2   178.32.38.187, 178.32.38.52, 178.32.38.50, 178.32.38.4, 178.32.36.223, 178.32.35.197, 178.32.34.254, 178.32.32.160, 178.32.32.159, 178.32.32.76, 178.32.32.39, 178.32.32.38, 178.32.32.26
3   178.32.33.61, 178.32.33.57
3   178.32.38.180, 178.32.38.119, 178.32.38.64, 178.32.38.62, 178.32.37.215, 178.32.35.108, 178.32.35.42, 178.32.34.242, 178.32.34.237, 178.32.34.1, 178.32.33.60, 178.32.33.59, 178.32.32.78, 178.32.33.56
4   178.32.39.6, 178.32.38.186, 178.32.38.115, 178.32.38.58, 178.32.37.216, 178.32.34.236, 178.32.33.206, 178.32.33.66, 178.32.33.55, 178.32.33.54, 178.32.32.77, 178.32.32.40, 178.32.32.33, 178.32.38.166
4   178.32.33.53, 178.32.38.167
4   178.32.33.68
```

Comment: What about countifs() ?

Comment: Do you have any examples?  Went through several iterations of countfs and did not find anything that worked in this scenario.

Comment: Well, provide data we can copy and work with. Also use textsplit() to separate the IP addresses into separate cells on the same row. then find() may work better than substitute()... Many examples of the use of countifs() exist on here and in the Excel help.

Comment: I edited the question with the requested data.

Comment: They all start with 178. or 14. so is that criteria relevant? Do you just want a count of IP addresses per zone, regardless of the first three digits? Is the expected result Zone 1, 3; Zone 2, 18; Zone 3, 16; Zone 4, 17?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted, then the following formulas should work to accomplish the desired output.*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A12</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, A1:A10,
     φ, B1:B10,
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(α,MMULT(N(α=TOROW(α)),LEN(φ)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(φ,",",))+1))))
```

---

**Edit:**

**As per comments of OP**

> *Thank you. This is a good start and looks like it is going to work.*
> *Only need one change. The first octet in the IP address is important.*
> *There may be other IP addresses listed, but I only want to count the*
> *ones that start with 178. or 14. Can you adjust this function to do*
> *that?*

---

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>A12</kbd>

```
=LET(
     α, TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(", "&B1:B10,", ",SEQUENCE(,99)),"."),
     φ, TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(α,{"178","14"})),A1:A10),3),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(φ,MMULT(N(φ=TOROW(φ)),φ^0))))
```

---

- α --> First split the `IP` addresses data into columns,
- φ --> Return an array of `Zones` stacked into a single column for those have `IP` addresses starting with `178.` & `14.` by excluding the rest which don't start with the same.
- Lastly, do a matrix product using <kbd>MMULT( )</kbd> of two arrays to get the counts, and by wrapping within a <kbd>UNIQUE()</kbd> after using <kbd>HSTACK( )</kbd> to combine both the arrays, excludes the duplicates.

---

Also, the above formula assumes per row there will be a max of `99` IP Addresses, if its not, then replace the `99` with this to make it dynamic -- `MAX(LEN(B1:B10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1:B10,",",))+1)` , that said the formula will be,

```
=LET(
     Ψ, MAX(LEN(B1:B10)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B1:B10,",",))+1),
     α, TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(", "&B1:B10,", ",SEQUENCE(,Ψ)),"."),
     φ, TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(α,{"178","14"})),A1:A10),3),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(φ,MMULT(N(φ=TOROW(φ)),φ^0))))
```

---

[image]

---

Updated Formula:

[image]

---

The formula is updated as per OP's comments:

[image]

---

OP Says:

> *Thank you. I see it working with data in the same spreadsheet. If I*
> *try to reference cells in another spreadsheet it does not appear to*
> *work. Where 'All_Devices_Requiring_IP_Space' is the other spreadhseet*
> *in the same workbook and IP addresses are in column E and zone numbers*
> *are in column D.*
>
> *I see it working in your link. However, every time I cut and paste the*
> *formula into a new cell i get the #CALC! error in my spreadsheet.*
>
> *I found the problem. The function does not take blank spaces in the*
> *zone column. The data must exist in every row of both columns. This*
> *won't work: ` 1 178.32.33.68 5 14.38.227.88 5 14.38.227.103*
> *14.38.227.104 178.32.33.68 14.38.227.88 5 14.38.227.103 6 14.38.227.104*

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=LET(
     δ, FILTER(All_Devices_Requiring_IP_Space!D1:E27,All_Devices_Requiring_IP_Space!D1:D27<>""),
     Ψ, MAX(LEN(INDEX(δ,,2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(δ,,2),",",))+1),
     α, TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(", "&INDEX(δ,,2),", ",SEQUENCE(,Ψ)),"."),
     Φ, TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(α,{"178","14"})),INDEX(δ,,1)),3),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(Φ,MMULT(N(Φ=TOROW(Φ)),Φ^0))))
```

---

Comment: Thank you.  This is a good start and looks like it is going to work.  Only need one change.  The first octet in the IP address is important.  There may be other IP addresses listed, but I only want to count the ones that start with 178. or 14.  Can you adjust this function to do that?

Comment: Thank you.  I see it working with data in the same spreadsheet.  If I try to reference cells in another spreadsheet it does not appear to work.  Where 'All_Devices_Requiring_IP_Space' is the other spreadhseet in the same workbook and IP addresses are in column E and zone numbers are in column D.

Comment: I see it working in your link.  However, every time I cut and paste the formula into a new cell i get the #CALC! error in my spreadsheet.

Comment: I found the problem.  The function does not take blank spaces in the zone column.  The data must exist in every row of both columns.  This won't work:
`
1 178.32.33.68
5 14.38.227.88
5 14.38.227.103
 14.38.227.104
 178.32.33.68
 14.38.227.88
5 14.38.227.103
6 14.38.227.104
`

Comment: My apologies.  The text editor is difficult and restrictive.  I edited the spreadsheet your created in the cloud.  You'll notice the blank spaces in column D.  If you fill those in with a number, the function works.  We are still working on assigning zone numbers to servers, so that column still has a lot of blanks right now.  I know we can apply the function after that work is completed and it will work, but it would be nice to have it working as we complete the zone assignments.

Comment: That got it!  Thank you very much for your support.  It was excellent!

Comment: Final solution:

`=LET(
     δ, FILTER(Sheet2!D2:E331,Sheet2!D2:D331<>""),
     Ψ, MAX(LEN(INDEX(δ,,2))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX(δ,,2),",",))+1),
     α, TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(", "&INDEX(δ,,2),", ",SEQUENCE(,Ψ)),"."),
     Φ, TOCOL(IFS(ISNUMBER(XMATCH(α,{"172","12"})),INDEX(δ,,1)),3),
     UNIQUE(HSTACK(Φ,MMULT(N(Φ=TOROW(Φ)),Φ^0))))`

Comment: Are you still there?  Just noticed the output by zone is not ordered, so results are listed as they are encountered in the spreadsheet.  I cannot manually order it as it is an array.

Comment: `Zone # IPs Req'd
3 162
7 9
9 202
5 15
1 1
4 23
2 9`

I need it to list the entries in numberical order rather than in the order they are encountered as the function enumerates the column downward.

Comment: @isd503 you `SORT()` function in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

### Count Substrings

```
=LET(data,A2:B21,ucol,1,vcol,2,crit,{"A.";"B."},dlm,", ",
    ud,CHOOSECOLS(data,ucol),
    vd,CHOOSECOLS(data,vcol),
    u,UNIQUE(ud),
    v,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,LET(
        f,FILTER(vd,ud=r),
        sc,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(dlm,,f),dlm),
        vc,COUNT(SEARCH(TOCOL(crit&"*"),sc)),
    vc))),
HSTACK(u,v))
```

[image]

```
=LET(data,A2:B21,ucol,1,vcol,2,crit,{"A.";"B."},dlm,", ",
    ud,CHOOSECOLS(data,ucol),
    vd,CHOOSECOLS(data,vcol),
    u,UNIQUE(ud),
HSTACK(u,BYROW(u,LAMBDA(r,
    COUNT(SEARCH(TOCOL(crit&"*"),
        TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(dlm,,
            FILTER(vd,ud=r)),dlm)))))))
```